# How to create a loop to run 2 variable generalized regression models?

Tags: r

I have 19 variables and I want to run 19 different regressions that consist of 2 independent variables from my dataset.

*Update -This is my dataset's structure:

```
$ Failure_Response_Var_Yr: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ exp_var_nocorr_2       : num  4.61 5.99 6.13 3.17 4.4 ...
 $ exp_var_nocorr_3       : num  4.16 5.46 5.24 2.86 3.72 ...
 $ exp_var_nocorr_4       : num  0.00191 2.23004 0.5613 1.07986 0.99836 ...
 $ exp_var_nocorr_5       : num  0.709 2.79 6.846 15.478 11.418 ...
 $ exp_var_nocorr_6       : num  0.724 0.497 1.782 0.156 2.525 ...
 $ exp_var_nocorr_7       : num  0 168.17 92.041 0.584 265.338 ...
 $ exp_var_nocorr_8       : num  -38.64 4.89 1.5 24.8 16.56 ...
 $ exp_var_nocorr_9       : num  116 88.3 56.4 60.6 57.6 ...
 $ exp_var_nocorr_10      : num  0 10.3 0 93.7 0 ...
 $ exp_var_nocorr_11      : num  1.02 1.23 1.31 2.06 1.33 ...
 $ exp_var_nocorr_12      : num  60 140 124 275 203 ...
 $ exp_var_nocorr_13      : num  10.835 5.175 1.838 0.347 0.783 ...
 $ exp_var_nocorr_14      : num  59 60.2 87.2 42.2 84.2 ...
 $ exp_var_nocorr_15      : num  61.9 68.3 99 50.2 103.9 ...
 $ exp_var_nocorr_16      : num  4.4 11.24 8.23 6.9 8.84 ...
 $ exp_var_nocorr_17      : num  6.43 18.62 10.72 15.62 10.35 ...
```

I wrote this code:
    `col17 <- names(my.sample)[-c(1:9,26:29)]`

Such that now `dput(col17)` gives out:
 `c("exp_var_nocorr_2", "exp_var_nocorr_3", "exp_var_nocorr_4", "exp_var_nocorr_5", "exp_var_nocorr_6", "exp_var_nocorr_7", "exp_var_nocorr_8", "exp_var_nocorr_9", "exp_var_nocorr_10", "exp_var_nocorr_11", "exp_var_nocorr_12", "exp_var_nocorr_13", "exp_var_nocorr_14", "exp_var_nocorr_15", "exp_var_nocorr_16", "exp_var_nocorr_17" )`

```
`logit.test2 <- vector("list", length(col17))  
#start of loop #
for(i in seq_along(col17)){
  for(k in seq_along(col17)){
    logit.test2[i] <- glm(reformulate(col17[i]+col17[k], "Failure_Response_Var_Yr"), 
                          family=binomial(link='logit'), data=my.sample)
  }
}`

# end of loop #
```

but it printed out this problem:
`"Error in col17[i] + col17[k] : non-numeric argument to binary operator"`

Can anybody hand me out a code that can fix this problem?

Comment: I guess without providing sample data, this is not easy to resolve. Maybe add the output of `dput(col17)` to your question.

Comment: Safest bet is probably to construct the formula before passing it to `glm`. You can use `paste` or `sprintf` and wrap it around into `as.formula`.

Comment: Your use of `reformulate` is wrong. Please study the documentation again. It clearly say the first argument is a character vector, i.e. `col17[c(i, k)]`.

Comment: revise `col17[i]+col17[k]` to `names(col17)[c(i, k)]` maybe

Comment: Your for loop mistakes. It generate 17*17 regression but the length of list is just 17.

Comment: By applying a character vector, such that `col17[c(i,k)]` 
I write the following:

`for(i in seq_along(col17)){
  for(k in seq_along(col17)){
    logit.test2[i] <- glm(reformulate(col17[c(i,k)], "Failure_Response_Var_Yr"), family=binomial(link='logit'), data=my.sample)
  }
}`

Yet, get the `Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` whenever I 
try to see the summary of the regressions or the coefficients.

Comment: When you say that "You can use paste or sprintf and wrap it around into as.formula" can you please illustrate the code I should use? Because I tried to apply it by myself and I certainly got it wrong because I am not really experienced using `as.formula` in a loop such as this.